# How to only allow alphanumeric on textbox using pure HTML

Tags: html, string, textbox

Suppose I have a textbox, and I want it to only accept alphanumeric characters (not case sensitive). I already did it by using javascript and regex.test() but I want the simplest implementation possible. **Can this be done by using HTML only?** For example, I know that we can limit a textbox to accept numbers by doiing `<input type="number">`. But I want the textbox to accept both text and number type and restrict special characters. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this feature for [input patterns](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

You can do that:

```
<input type="text" id="onlyletters" name="onlyletters" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Only letters">
```

Inside the pattern attribute, you can use any regular expression.

Comment: Since the question is asking for alphanumeric, you can also add `0-9` for numbers: ... pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element then the answer is no.

If, however, you are using the `input` element, then the answer is yes - See [specifying a pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern), it can accept a Javascript regex, but it's done only with HTML.